# Can't find Bonjour service in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, bonjour

I am trying to install the Tivo desktop app. During the installation it says it found a newer version of Bonjour. Then when it tries to run, it says Bonjour service is not running. I had iTunes installed before which should have installed Bonjour. I also installed the Bonjour SDK.
Yet when I go through the list of services, I don't see the Bonjour service. I see a Bonjour folder under c:\Program files and another one c:\Porgram files (x86).

What's the full name of the service? Did Windows 8 change the behavior of Bonjour service?

Comment: +1, I reinstalled Bonjour on a Windows 7 64-bit machine, and I can't see the service either.